# Jquery Setting Value of Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field and i am trying to set its value using its class

```
<form:input path="userName" id="userName" title="Choose A Unique UserName" readonly="${userNameStatus}" class="formData"/>
```

Which renders as:

```
<input id="userName" name="userName" title="Choose A Unique UserName" class="formData" type="text" value=""/>
```

I am using the following jquery but this does not seem to work. Can someone tell me where i am going wrong.

```
$(".formData").html("");
```

**Edited JQuery Function that handles the event**

```
$('#reset').click(function (){
            $("#userNameErr").text(""); 
            $('#badgeNoErr').text("");

            $(".errors").html("");

            $(".formData").val("");

        });
```

nor is `$(".formData").text("")` or `$(".formData").val("")` working.

Comment: What's the *actual* HTML that's produced? As opposed to whatever server-side script you're working with?

Comment: the actual html is <input id="userName" name="userName" title="Choose A Unique UserName" class="formData" type="text" value=""/>

Comment: I am trying to set the value in this field to null when i click on a reset button

Comment: Seems to be behaving fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FtnLM/ `:)`

Comment: _"trying to set the value in this field to null"_ - To null? Or to an empty string? `$(".formData").val("")` should do it.

Comment: yes to an empty string but $(".formData").val("") is not working

Comment: Please show the JavaScript code that creates the button click event handler. Is it in a document ready handler? If your script is in the `<head>` (or otherwise before the elements in question) you won't be able to assign a click handler without using document ready (or onload, but don't do that).

Comment: yes it is the other statements above it is working

Comment: The reset of all other fields are working? Edit: Sry, already answered

Comment: Is it an `<input type="reset">` button - because that would normally change the value of fields in the form too. Try using `.preventDefault()` or adding `return false;` to the end of the click handler, or use a `type="button"` input.

Comment: yes the other fields are working but the input fields aren't i am submitting to the server thou so i am not sure if that's causing the problem.

Comment: this is my jsfiddle and its not working http://jsfiddle.net/FtnLM/1/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This should work.

```
$(".formData").val("valuesgoeshere")
```

For empty

```
$(".formData").val("")
```

If this does not work, you should post a jsFiddle.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".resetInput").on("click", function() {
    $(".formData").val("");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="formData" value="yoyoyo">


<button class="resetInput">Click Here to reset</button>
```

Comment: This does not work its a Spring tag i am using so i am not sure if its different but it renders normal html so i am not sure whats the problem

Answer (score 5):

If the input field has a class name formData use this :
`$(".formData").val("data")`

If the input field has an id attribute name formData use this :
`$("#formData").val("data")`

If the input name is given use this :
`$("input[name='formData']").val("data")`

You can also mention the type. Then it will refer to all the inputs of that type and the given class name:
`$("input[type='text'].formData").val("data")`

Answer (score 1):

change your jquery loading setting to **onload** in jsfiddle . . .it works . . .

Comment: So why is it my code isnt working i have this in the document.ready??

Comment: u had ur initial setting to nowrap (head) . . .it works on domREADY ... i can't figure what is the problem with nowrap head setting

Answer (score 1):

use this code for set value in input tag by another id.

```
$(".formdata").val(document.getElementById("fsd").innerHTML);
```

or
use this code for set value in input tag using classname="formdata"

```
$(".formdata").val("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.formData').attr('value','YOUR_VALUE')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just write this script. use input element for this.

```
$("input").val("valuesgoeshere");
```

or by id="fsd" you write this code.

```
$("input").val(document.getElementById("fsd").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -5):

Put your jQuery function in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

It's surely solved.

Comment: Please edit your other answer instead of posting a new answer. Also take a look at the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help