# Dynamic Element Adding and Duplicating with method perameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry about the title. I didn't know how to explain something as specific as this.

So I've been creating a simple form that can dynamically remove and duplicate fields using jQuery. Working great!

**Problem** - I have a function that currently clones the last_input (see **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge5r36pm/)** for example). This works great for the duplicate button but for the add button I'm just wanting to add a new blank row.

I was wondering if it would be easy to add an extra function to fix this, or is there a different parameter I could use when I call the addLine() method?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1">
        <input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate">
        <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove">
    </div>
</form>
<hr>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1">
        <input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate">
        <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove">
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
function addLine($inputLine) {
    var $form = $inputLine.closest('form');
    var $newElement = $inputLine.clone(true).hide();

    $newElement.insertAfter($inputLine);
    $newElement.slideDown();
    $form.find('.remove').show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    'use strict';
    $('.remove').hide();

    //Add Feild
    $('.add').click(function () {
        addLine($(this).closest('form').find('.input_line:last'));
    });

    //Duplicate Feild
    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        addLine($(this).closest('.input_line'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra parameter to `addLine()` like this maybe

```
function addLine($inputLine, isDuplicate) {
    var $form = $inputLine.closest('form');
    var $newElement = $inputLine.clone(true).hide();
    if(!isDuplicate) {
        $newElement.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    }

    $newElement.insertAfter($inputLine);
    $newElement.slideDown();
    $form.find('.remove').show();
}
```

And addLine can be called like this

```
$('.add').click(function() {
  addLine($(this).closest('form').find('.input_line:last'), 0);
});
//Duplicate Feild
$('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function() {
  addLine($(this).closest('.input_line'), 1);
});
```

Here is the updated demo **[http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ge5r36pm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ge5r36pm/2/)**

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I'v got a question.

instead of 
    `.find('input[type="text"]')` could you explain what is wrong with `.find('.input_line')`? Thanks

Comment: `.input_line` is a div. What we want to do is catch each input element and set their value to null.

Comment: I'm confused how that is settings the value to null though?

Comment: `$newElement.find('input[type="text"]')` will find all the input elements with `type="text"` then `.val('')` sets the value to `'' (empty string)`. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994697)

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla you said this will find all the input elements, is this for the entire DOM or just within the form tags?

Comment: it will be only the input elements within `$newElement` div. [Check ths reference](http://api.jquery.com/find/)