# Set Input Value to jQuery Variable

Tags: html, jquery, variables

I'm trying to set an input field to the value of a jQuery variable but it's refusing to cooperate.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Essentially, I'm trying to get equipment failure counts to display in an input textbox so I can write the value back to a table.  Each failure counts as 1 and is added to a total (truckFailsTot variable) when users click a Y/N radio button next to each type of failure. The example below just includes one failure for brevity.

HTML

```
div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12"><label class="col-form-label" for="TruckFailCount">TruckFailCount</label> 
<input class="form-control" ${disabled( 'TruckFailCount')} id="TruckFailCount" maxlength="13" name="TruckFailCount" title="truckFailCount" type="text" value="${row.truckFailCount?html}" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery - I've commented out my failed attemps below.  It seems like such a simple thing, yet nothing is working.

```
    jQuery('body').on("change",'#TruckAirCompressor',function(){
        
         if (this.value == "Fail") {
             fail_TruckAirCompressor = 1;
    
         } 
         else if (this.value == "Pass") { 
             fail_TruckAirCompressor = 0;
             
         }
         else { 
    
         }
        
        
        truckFailsTot = fail_TruckAirCompressor + fail_TruckAirLines + fail_TruckBattery 
            + fail_TruckBeltsHoses + fail_TruckBody + fail_TruckBrakesAccessories + fail_TruckBrakesParking
            + fail_TruckBrakesService + fail_TruckClutch + fail_TruckCouplingDevicesHitch 
            + fail_TruckDefrosterHeater + fail_TruckDriveLine + fail_TruckExhaustMuffler
            + fail_TruckFluidLevels + fail_TruckFuelTanks + fail_TruckHorn + fail_TruckLights
            + fail_TruckMirrors + fail_TruckSafetyEquipment + fail_TruckSteeringMechanism
            + fail_TruckTiresRimsWheels + fail_TruckWindows + fail_TruckWindshieldWipers;


        //  var t = truckFailsTot;
        //  $('#TruckFailCount').value(t);
        //  document.getElementById("#TruckFailCount").innerHTML=t;

        //   var val1 = truckFailsTot;
        //  $('#TruckFailCount').val(val1);

        //   var fooBar = 1;
        //  $('#TruckFailCount').val(fooBar);

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if this ever gets called by adding a console.log or an alert somewhere in the callback function

Comment: The code that sets the value is commented out. If that's not your actual code, post the real thing.

Comment: `1=1` is a syntax error, you can't assign to a literal.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I had added 1=1 earlier but took it out and forgot to remove from the sample. Please disregard.  Regarding the commented out code, it contains the different variations I'd tried.  None of them worked.

Comment: @CornelRaiu, yes, I've added alerts there and they are triggering.  The value just isn't being set, which I can't figure out.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Which code are you using to set the value? You can't use `innerHTML` for an input element, it has to be the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery Setting Value of Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994646/jquery-setting-value-of-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the correct syntax needed to assign a jQuery variable to an input text field and wanted to update my question in case someone else runs across a similar issue.  All the jQuery documentation I'd come across recommended setting the value of the input field using .val(). Doing so didn't work for me, but the below code did.

```
var truckFailsTot;
truckFailsTot = fail_TruckAirCompressor + fail_TruckAirLines + fail_TruckBattery;
document.getElementById("TruckFailCount").value = truckFailsTot;
```